# How can I set up IIS website (not Application Pool) identity fields (username & password) via PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, iis

Looking for help on how to set the IIS **website** - NOT application pool - identity fields via the PowerShell WebAdministration module. I have many IIS servers (with many web sites on each) that need to have their passwords reset.

[Here's where the identity fields would be set manually](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EE0Nu.jpg)

I already have the commands needed to modify the application pool identity, but I cannot find anything on modifying the **website** identity fields.

TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome, SamJ! Have you tried something like this script?

```
$iisSitePath = "IIS:\Sites\" + $siteName
$website = get-item $iisSitePath
$website.virtualDirectoryDefaults.userName = "domain\username"
$website.virtualDirectoryDefaults.password = "password"
$website | set-item
```

Found on [this blog](http://thejohnreynolds.com/post/10149304231/set-iis-physical-path-credentials-with-powershell)

There's also an option to poke XML into the applicationhost.config file:

```
Set-WebConfiguration -Filter "/system.applicationHost/sites/site[@name='Test']/application[@path='/']/virtualDirectory[@path='/']" -Value @{userName='DOMAIN\TestUser'; password='Pa55word'}
```

Comment: Rich ... My apologies for the delay ... I only received an email earlier today that you had responded.... Your answer worked!  This was my first question on SO, so I hope I've correctly marked it as the answer.